# Docker unable to find image locally on Synology

Tags: docker, synology

I'm running Docker on my Synology DS918+ and I'm looking to run the jetbrains/teamcity-server container.

When I run the following command:

```
 sudo docker run teamcity-server -v /volume2/docker/teamcity-server/datadir/:/data/teamcity_server/datadir -v /volume2/docker/teamcity-server/logs/:/opt/teamcity/logs -p 8001:8001 jetbrains/teamcity-server:latest
```

I get a result back that it can't find the image locally:

```
Unable to find image 'teamcity-server:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for teamcity-server, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I believe that I have confirmed that I have the image installed locally because when I run the command:

```
sudo docker images
```

I get the following result:

```
REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jetbrains/teamcity-server        latest              bfe4a2f841c1        2 weeks ago         2.2GB
```

Comment: (Are you missing a `--name` option immediately after `docker run`?)

Comment: Did my response solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use --name before the container name (teamcity-server). Otherwise, docker will think that it is the image that you are trying to pull and error out.

```
sudo docker run --name teamcity-server -v /volume2/docker/teamcity-server/datadir/:/data/teamcity_server/datadir -v /volume2/docker/teamcity-server/logs/:/opt/teamcity/logs -p 8001:8001 jetbrains/teamcity-server:latest
```